# PDO: Can't pull data from a 4th table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I am trying to pull data from 4 tables. When I pull data from 3(user_table, posts, followers) of the MySQL tables, the data is retrieved just fine. Its when i attempt to pull specific columns from the 4th table(post_likes) where I get problems. All the data simply does not show at all.

Here's the database structure:

user_table: `user_id, username, name`

posts: `post_id, body, user_id, likes`

followers: `follower_id, user_id, follower_id`

post_likes: `likes_id, post_id, user_id`

Connection script:

```
class DB {

      private static function connect() {
              $pdo = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8','root','');
              $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
              return $pdo;
      }

      public static function query($query, $params = array()) {
             $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
             $statement->execute($params);
             if (explode(' ', $query)[0] == 'SELECT') {
             $data = $statement->fetchAll();
             return $data;
             }
     }
  }
```

script that works pulling data from 3 tables:

```
$posts = DB::query('SELECT posts.post_id, posts.body, posts.likes, 
users_table.username, users_table.name FROM users_table, posts, followers
WHERE posts.user_id = followers.user_id
AND users_table.user_id = posts.user_id
AND follower_id = :userid
ORDER BY posts.posted_at DESC', array(':userid'=>$userid));
```

script that doesn't work pulling data from 4 tables:

```
$posts = DB::query('SELECT posts.post_id, posts.body, post_likes.post_id, 
post_likes.user_id, posts.likes, users_table.username, users_table.name 
FROM users_table, posts, followers, post_likes
WHERE posts.user_id = followers.user_id
AND users_table.user_id = posts.user_id
AND follower_id = :userid
ORDER BY posts.posted_at DESC', array(':userid'=>$userid));
```

Any help i can for this? thanx

Comment: Remove PDO from the equation and test your query on MySQL directly.  Is any data returned?  It sounds like the query simply results in zero records.  What records are returned without a `WHERE` clause at all?  How are these tables being joined?  Hint: Explicit joins are much easier to manage than implicit ones.  Instead of just separating the tables by commas, use actual `JOIN` clauses.  Maybe the implicit join isn't doing what you expect it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do is :

```
SELECT 
posts.post_id, posts.body, post_likes.post_id, 
post_likes.user_id, posts.likes, users_table.username, users_table.name 
FROM 
users_table 
inner join posts on users_table.user_id = posts.user_id
inner join followers on posts.user_id = followers.user_id
inner join post_likes on post_likes.id = <your condition>
WHERE
follower_id = :userid
ORDER BY posts.posted_at DESC
```

we assume that follower_id column exists only in 1 of the table else ambiguity error will be thrown

Answer (score 1):

The reason your 4 table query is failing is due to adding in the **post_likes** table to the query but not providing any sort of link from the current data set to the post_likes table.

Notice all of your where clauses link your tables together. There is no where clause linking in your **post_likes** table.

My asummption is you need to update your WHERE clause to this:

```
WHERE posts.user_id = followers.user_id
AND post_likes.post_id = posts.post_id //Link post_likes here
AND users_table.user_id = posts.user_id
AND follower_id = :userid
```

EDIT: as david states you should be using actual JOIN commands.

Comment: this still gives me the same result